# How to deal with machine generated changes with git?

Tags: git, build, web-deployment

The project I have been stuck with has huge convoluted build system, changing a single css file requires running build script for entire project. Every alternative to standard web techs is used js->coffeescript, css->scss, etc. So build step changes a lot of files every time. It's made sure to thoroughly abuse mixins, and make everything as OOP/in different files as much as possible.

Now if i change one file i want to see only changes that matter. But git pull request show all changes inside `machine_generated/` folder also.

What's a solution around this.

I can't exclude them they need to be updated on server since they are served.

Comment: Excluding them from the VCS is usually the correct solution.  In this case, the intermediate step of generating them *for* the server can be done by an intermediate *agent*: the deploy script should check out the revision to be deployed, run the generator, and deploy the result.  Admittedly, retrofitting good practices into some existing ball-of-hair can be problematic.

Comment: Is it a strategy of your team to commit the changes in `machine_generated/`? If not, you could just `git add` the file you modified and let alone the  machine_generated before you run `git commit`. If the machine_generated can help others to skip some build steps, it's worth to commit.

Comment: how would i push it to server if i use git to push to server like on heroku, if those files aren't being excluded from git. What would the script would have to do

Comment: @ElpieKay Pushing latest auto generated code is important as yes you said. I want to do that but i also dont want to see them in git commits like some solution, i can't imagine the solution

Comment: If the built files are included and change in every commit you are headed towards doom my friend. Do whatever it takes to get those generated files out of version control or your repo will get so big that it will be unreasonable to ever clone it on a different machine. Make a separate repo and archive the current one if you have to. The build server is supposed to generate those files as well, not just your dev machine. For a more detailed solution you will have to tell me more about your specific setup.

Comment: I've this problem for the company i work for, and i dont think i have any say in this matter, but i am interested in knowing the better way. So what would be the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just use git diff FILENAME.
say i have a file named style.css and i only want to see changes in that file only, then i'll run.......

git diff style.css

Comment: i get it, but i meant for other people reviewing my pull request they have to look at machine generated files. They have to dig out the file i changed out of 30 auto updated files

Comment: why not just include the file name you edited in your commit message